# Unable to release silent app updates after migrating to app center, takes me to sign up in a microsoft page

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I have an android app running on xamarin forms which was originally released under hockeyapp, since the last release, I have migrated to appcenter. During the migration, I had also missed adding the appcenter.distribute nuget package to my project. Having said that, previously, when the app was under hockey app, when we release the app users will see an update notification indicating that an update is available. Since I migrated to appcenter, I do not see the update notification popup in my app. I am fairly new to android and appcenter and not sure, if the appcenter.distribute is the right package that I should be looking at? Because, when I use the appcenter.distribute as well, it does not popup as a notification for update in the app, but takes us to a microsoft page in the browser to sign up. All this time my app updates were within the app as a silent update, where users will see a notification within the app and choosing download will download the update and install it.

Not sure what I am missing here and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing everything correct. The sign up page should appear only once on the first app start. It saves some important information which then enables checking for new releases and the dialog. 
If you log in, does it still not work for you?

Comment: Hi @annaoomph.. Yes.. Managed to get in touch with appcenter support and that's the same explanation given by them. Since I migrated my app from Hockeyapp to appcenter, this behavior is quite different as Hockeyapp supported side loading. As per support, looks like Microsoft is working on this and something should be out to fix this especially for hockeyapp users, mid-late Jan 2020. Also the issue in my case where the login page kept coming up was because the version code in my app build and in appcenter were different. After I fixed this,I started getting the count down page with the redirect

Comment: Update: The newer releases of appcenter, no longer launch the browser page. They work as a silent onboarding step in the background.